# Listen for events without knowing the contract address

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

Hello is it possible to listen for events without providing the contract address as part of the filter object. I have following case:

Multiple times the same contract will be instantiated and i will need to listen for events from all of the instances. Lets say this contract contains event Created() can i somehow subscribe to all Created() events that are happening on chain and when i receive to check from which address is emitted and if it's one of these address for who i do care about to store the event?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is similar to try to listen for any person saying "Hello !" from every phone number that is used.

But back to the question, I have not practiced for a long time, but I think it is *not* possible using events.

However, you can scan every single transaction of every single block to find the "Created" events in it.